# How to run cron job in android app which runs in the background and displays clickable notification

Tags: json, android-fragments

Is there a way a cron job can be coded to run in the background of an app every few seconds posting a json object (whose values change based on a particular fragment being viewed) to a php server and displays a clickable toast when a particular response is received?

If so how may I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the android job scheduler:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling

Or, this library is also quite nice: https://github.com/evernote/android-job